# Flask errorhandler not catching exception

Tags: python, flask

I'm having an issue where whenever the `auth.get_token_auth_header` function raises an `AuthError` it just triggers a 500 Server Error and triggers the Flask debugger. It should be catching the exception and returning the relevant error/status code to the user, but it doesn't.

If I change the `@app.errorhandler(AuthError)` to `@app.errorhandler(Exception)` it seems to work. Have I done something in order to prevent the specificity of `AuthError`?

app.py:

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.http import HTTP_STATUS_CODES

import constants
from api.views import api
from client.views import client
from exceptions import AuthError
from extensions import db

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static', static_folder='./static')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.secret_key = constants.SECRET_KEY
app.debug = True

db.init_app(app)

app.register_blueprint(api)
app.register_blueprint(client)


@app.errorhandler(AuthError)
def handle_auth_error(e):
    response = {
        "message": HTTP_STATUS_CODES.get(e.status_code),
        "description": e.error,
    }
    return response, e.status_code


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

auth.py:

```
import json
import os
from functools import wraps

from flask import request, _request_ctx_stack
from jose import jwt
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen

from web.constants import AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL, AUTH0_CLIENT_ID, AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, AUTH0_DOMAIN, AUTH0_AUDIENCE
from web.exceptions import AuthError

AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL = os.environ.get(AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL)
AUTH0_CLIENT_ID = os.environ.get(AUTH0_CLIENT_ID)
AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get(AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET)
AUTH0_DOMAIN = os.environ.get(AUTH0_DOMAIN)
AUTH0_BASE_URL = 'https://' + AUTH0_DOMAIN
AUTH0_AUDIENCE = os.environ.get(AUTH0_AUDIENCE)
ALGORITHMS = ["RS256"]


# Format error response and append status code
def get_token_auth_header():
    """Obtains the Access Token from the Authorization Header
    """
    auth = request.headers.get("Authorization", None)
    if not auth:
        raise AuthError({
            "code": "authorization_header_missing",
            "description":
                "Authorization header is expected"
        }, 401)

    parts = auth.split()

    if parts[0].lower() != "bearer":
        raise AuthError({
            "code": "invalid_header",
            "description":
                "Authorization header must start with"
                " Bearer"
        }, 401)
    elif len(parts) == 1:
        raise AuthError({
            "code": "invalid_header",
            "description": "Token not found"
        }, 401)
    elif len(parts) > 2:
        raise AuthError({
            "code": "invalid_header",
            "description":
                "Authorization header must be"
                " Bearer token"
        }, 401)

    token = parts[1]
    return token


def requires_scope(required_scope):
    """Determines if the required scope is present in the Access Token
    Args:
        required_scope (str): The scope required to access the resource
    """
    token = get_token_auth_header()
    unverified_claims = jwt.get_unverified_claims(token)
    if unverified_claims.get("scope"):
        token_scopes = unverified_claims["scope"].split()
        for token_scope in token_scopes:
            if token_scope == required_scope:
                return True
    return False


def requires_auth(f):
    """Determines if the Access Token is valid
    """

    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = get_token_auth_header()
        jsonurl = urlopen("https://" + AUTH0_DOMAIN + "/.well-known/jwks.json")
        jwks = json.loads(jsonurl.read())
        unverified_header = jwt.get_unverified_header(token)
        rsa_key = {}
        for key in jwks["keys"]:
            if key["kid"] == unverified_header["kid"]:
                rsa_key = {
                    "kty": key["kty"],
                    "kid": key["kid"],
                    "use": key["use"],
                    "n": key["n"],
                    "e": key["e"]
                }
        if rsa_key:
            try:
                payload = jwt.decode(
                    token,
                    rsa_key,
                    algorithms=ALGORITHMS,
                    audience=AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
                    issuer="https://" + AUTH0_DOMAIN + "/"
                )
            except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
                raise AuthError({
                    "code": "token_expired",
                    "description": "token is expired"
                }, 401)
            except jwt.JWTClaimsError:
                raise AuthError({
                    "code": "invalid_claims",
                    "description":
                        "incorrect claims,"
                        "please check the audience and issuer"
                }, 401)
            except Exception:
                raise AuthError({
                    "code": "invalid_header",
                    "description":
                        "Unable to parse authentication"
                        " token."
                }, 401)

            _request_ctx_stack.top.current_user = payload
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        raise AuthError({
            "code": "invalid_header",
            "description": "Unable to find appropriate key"
        }, 401)

    return decorated
```

exceptions.py:

```
class AuthError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, error, status_code):
        self.error = error
        self.status_code = status_code
```

traceback:

```
web_1   | 172.19.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2021 18:01:02] "GET /api/v1/core/jobs HTTP/1.1" 500 -
web_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2088, in __call__
web_1   |     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
web_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
web_1   |     response = self.handle_exception(e)
web_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
web_1   |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
web_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
web_1   |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
web_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
web_1   |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
web_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
web_1   |     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
web_1   |   File "/web/api/auth.py", line 80, in decorated
web_1   |     token = get_token_auth_header()
web_1   |   File "/web/api/auth.py", line 27, in get_token_auth_header
web_1   |     raise AuthError({
web_1   | web.exceptions.AuthError: ({'code': 'authorization_header_missing', 'description': 'Authorization header is expected'}, 401)
```

Comment: The full traceback would be helpful.

Comment: @noslenkwah sorry, I've edited the question and appended the trace

Comment: It looks like you are throwing `web.exceptions.AuthError` and trying to handle `exceptions.AuthError`.  Both seem to exist (both imports succeed), but they are not the same.

Comment: @MennoHölscher ah, that's embarrassing. exceptions should have been a relative import. I have no idea why it wasn't complaining, I'll have to look in to it (python imports that is, again). Thanks for bringing that to my attention!

Answer (score -1):

Check this [doc](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html#custom-error-handlers) Flask-RESTful one, which yours is, it will be handled by handle_error(), and the only way to prevent or customise this is to implement your own API class, and override handle_error().

```
@app.errorhandler(AuthError)
def handle_error(e):
    response = {
        "message": HTTP_STATUS_CODES.get(e.status_code),
        "description": e.error,
    }
    return response, e.status_code
```

Comment: What makes you think I’m using Flask-restful?